# Assign external ip to kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

Context:

- We're working on an integration with one of our clients
- In order to get access to their systems, we need to establish a VPN connection
- For security reasons, we need to bind this VPN connection to a static IP on our side (basically, layer 4 security check enforced by a Juniper router; we use OpenSwan to connect to it).
- To do that, we must be connecting *from that IP* ; that is, we need to establish a socket connection, where the source IP corresponds to that static IP from the router's perspective (and, of course, that needs to route back to our pod successfully)
- Client's side has very limited resources ops-wise, so this security hoop is the only way to connect to their systems

While our current system is running (AWS) Kubernetes, which is:

- Made out of transient pods, transient nodes, with shifting IPs
- Can assign an ExternalIP to a service (which, in turn, can route it to a pod); however that, by default, makes no guarantees about the originator IP of the traffic initiated by that pod

For this reason, we set up an external box & assigned Elastic IP to it, as a binding for the VPN, exposing endpoints, and calling our Kubernetes Services. This introduces a single point of failure -if that box goes down, so does our integration.

Question: in what ways can this be made HA within the Kubernetes world, given the constrains on the first list above?

Comment: You might want to consider putting a Load balancer like nginx or haproxy in between and assign it your External static IP and then route them to your internal pods which can be replicated for HA. However , this still has the Single Point of Failure problem as you mentioned on the LB side , but it can be contained more easily than having this problem on your application side. Also, try to consider having two static IPs instead of one on the LB side , which can also provide a better HA architecture.

Comment: @fatcook this does not solve the problem, whereby an outgoing connection needs to be originating from the static IP. A connection made from the pod, from an outsider perspective, will always carry the node's IP (which is transient, and can change any time).

Comment: I am not sure I get the use case clearly then , using a reverse proxy mechanism you should be able to manage to show the connection is originating from your application itself.

Comment: Except the connection is not HTTP, openswan requires an _outgoing_ TCP connection, which appears to be initiating from that external IP.